# Why do I get the error "Container.name should not be null or empty"?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform

We are using terraform to import a ECS solution and for some reason, I can not get pass this error.

> aws_ecs_task_definition.clustername: ClientException: Container.name
> should not be null or empty. 09-Feb-2017 23:35:1 status code: 400

I believe this is coming form this json file, `service-prod-server.json`

```
#aws_ecs_task_definition
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "cluster-name" {
  family = "cluster-name"
  container_definitions = "${file("task-definitions/service-prod-server.json")}"
}
```

Here is the top portion of the service-prod-server.json config. I have the name there.

```
[
  {
    "name": "containername",
    "memory": 7000,
    "image": "imagename",
    "disableNetworking": false,
    "readonlyRootFilesystem": false,
```

I also have this config defined as well.

```
#aws_ecs_container_definition
data "aws_ecs_container_definition" "cluster-name" {
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.cluster-name.id}"
  container_name = "containername"
}
```

Let me know what you guys think

Comment: It looks like it works, but what about the directory structure?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the whole `service-prod-server.json` config (omitting any secret stuff you may have there)? That might help us reproducing the error.

Comment: Looks like it did work, I had to delete the existing environment. Once I did that and did a push, it worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For what it's worth, I got this same error in Terraform when trying to pass an entire task definition to `container_definitions`. Note that the `container_definitions` option should only be set to the [containerDefinitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definitions) section of the task definition (not the entire thing).

Comment: When you put it this way it seems so obvious.

Answer (score 9):

For me, I labeled the environment variable key incorrectly:

```
{ "key": "myvariable", "value": "myvalue" }
```

instead of

```
{ "name": "myvariable", "value": "myvalue" }
```

The difference is that I wrote `key` instead of `name` and that broke the whole container definition, which gave me this error.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question which was specifically about `Container.name`, however I upvote because I had the exact same issue, googling brought me here, and this syntax helped me fix my problem, I was doing something like `{ "myvariable": "value"}` - I hadn't provided the name at all, so thanks!

Comment: This answer helped me as I had made the same mistake causing Terraform to ignore my key/value pairs and set `environment` to `{}`. Thank You.